# Changing the value of some indexes of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying this simple code to search in an array and replace the elements that are greater than 1 to 1:

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([[1],[3],[1],[0],[9]])

for x in j:
    if abs(x) > 1 :
        j[x] = 1
```

But I get such errors:

> IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

Comment: @CarcigenicateL I edited my question

Comment: Try using `enumerate`, and use the enumerated index to change the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're doing is making all values if `absolute(j[i])` is greater than 1  to 1 then numpy has this capability built in and it's so simple it can be done in one line and more efficient than any python loop:

```
j[np.absolute(j) > 1] = 1
```

To show you how this would work:

```
#made 3 a negitive value to prove absolute works.
j = np.array([[1],[-3],[1],[0],[9]])

j[np.absolute(j) > 1] = 1
```

`j` is now:

```
[[1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you traverse an array in a `for` loop you are actually accessing the elements, not the index. After all, you are comparing `x` against `1`. You can retrieve the index in many ways, one of the common ones is to use `enumerate`, like so:

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([[1],[3],[1],[0],[9]])

for i,x in enumerate(j):    # i is the index, x is the value
    if abs(x) > 1 :
        j[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the for loop using `enumerate` to :

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([[1],[3],[1],[0],[9]])

for i,x in enumerate(j):
    if abs(x) > 1 :
        j[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

as you see in your error output

> IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5

you are trying to update a value at index 9 but your array is of size 5.
which clearly means you are not using the index of array but actually the value at index.

enumerate your array and run a loop with both index & value

```
for i,x in  enumerate(j):
    if abs(x) > 1 :
        j[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a two dimensional array? You have your elements in brackets within brackets "[[1],[3],[1],[0],[9]]" .... also, you're iterating over values, not indices: x is an array value "[3]" not an index "1".

Change to:

```
import numpy as np

j = np.array([1,3,1,0,9])

# Keep track of index starting at 0
i = 0
for x in j:
    if abs(x) > 1 :
        # change value at index i
        j[i] = 1
    # increment index
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace the for statement with this:

```
for x in range(len(j))
```